# Delete Outlook Appointment via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to make a Powershell Script which deletes Outlook Appointments on `User Site` and not with the Exchange Management Shell. I've already made a script, that creates an `Appointment` on `User Site` but I didn't find much about deleting `Appointments` on `User Site`.

Here is what I already tried:

1. Create `Appointment` on `User Site` (Maybe something can be reversed in this function?)

   ```
            $outlook = new-object -comObject Outlook.Application
            $olNamespace = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            $calendar = $olNamespace.Folders.Item("$Kalender") 
            $olAppointmentItem = 1

            $termin = $calendar.Items.Add("IPM.Appointment")


            $termin.start = ($Date)
            $termin.duration = ( 60 * 24  )
            $termin.subject = "Closed"
            $termin.ReminderSet = $False
            $termin.Categories = "Closed"
            $result = $termin.save()
   ```
2. Here i tried it with the Exchange Management Shell (but thats not the solution im looking for..)

   ```
    Search-Mailbox -Identity "User" -SearchQuery {Subject:"Test" AND Send:"04/20/2020"}

    New-ComplianceSearch -Name "RemoveCalendar1" -ExchangeLocation All -ContentMatchQuery "'calendar 
    subject line'"
   ```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its similar.  You just need to identify the item(s) you want to delete.  This is shown below using `Where-Object`

```
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$olNamespace = $outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$calendar = $olNamespace.Folders.Item("$Kalender") 

# Find appointments with Title 'Test' scheduled for today
$itemsToBeDeleted = $calendar.Items | Where-Object { $_.ConversationTopic -eq 'Test' -and $_.start.date -eq (Get-Date).date }

# Delete items
$itemsToBeDeleted.Delete()
```

This can be dangerous as there is potential to delete items unintentionally.  Be very specific with your filtering.  You may want to check `$itemsToBeDeleted.Count` prior to executing the delete command.

```
if ($itemsToBeDeleted.Count -gt 1) {
    $itemsToBeDeleted | Select-Object ConversationTopic, Start | Out-Host
    Write-Warning "Multiple items selected for deletion.  Are you sure you want to continue?" -WarningAction Inquire
}

# Delete items
$itemsToBeDeleted.Delete()
```